# obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to selenium. While running (debugging) my selenium tests (in C#), I am getting "obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context" and due to this none of the web elements are found.

I have used "Selenium.Support.PageObjects" & PageFactory to locate and initialize web elemements.

Can anyone help me out from this?

Below is snippet of my code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace TestFramework
{
    public class TestClass: TestBase
    {

        public TestClass(Driver driver): base(driver) { }

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='modal-footer']/button[@title='Yes']")]
        public IWebElement YesButton { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='modal-footer']/button[@title='No']")]
        public IWebElement NoButton { get; set; }


        public void ClickYesButton()
        {
        YesButton.Click();
        }
        public void ClickNoButton(int timeout = ConfigMT.DefaultTimeout)
        {
        NoButton.Click();
        }

    }
}
```

And TestBase class is:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace TestFramework
{

public class TestBase
{

    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    public Page(Driver driver)
    {
        this.Driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(this.Driver, this);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to this thread at the bottom of this answer, this appears to be a bug in the VS debugger.

A workaround mentioned is to go to `Debug>Options>Debugging>General` and click the checkbox to `Use the legacy C# and VB expressions evaluators`

While this worked for me, you still won't be able to check methods or properties on the element if that's what you're trying to do unfortunately.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f4e2bca-91dd-4919-8cbe-0adff2021ce8/debugging-transparent-proxy-objects-not-working-anymore-in-visual-studio-2015?forum=vsdebug

Comment: I tried that and the problem changes to "Cannot obtain fields or call methods on the instance of type ... because it is a proxy to a remote object"

Answer (score 0):

.NET PageFactory implementation was refactored in 2.46 and now uses instances of System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy to intercept method calls and populate your fields and properties marked with the appropriate attributes. Using the .NET Framework's proxy solution provides flexibility for other third-party projects to use the .NET PageFactory implementation, and thus will not be changing. It should be possible to create your own proxy solution that provides you with the debug properties in Visual Studio, but it would require a custom solution.